# Intuitive reasons for studying $J$-holomorphic curves with $W^{k,p}$ space?

Tags: geometry, analysis, partial-differential-equations, symplectic-geometry, differential-operators

Is there an intuitive (or geometric) reason why we need to consider $L^p$ Sobolev spaces instead of just considering $L^2$ when studying $J$-holomorphic curves?

The only reason I know is when proving some properties of the local linearized Cauchy-Riemann equation we need to use $L^p$ for $p>2$ to ensure some inequalities to be correct. But is there any geometric fact that will not be true for $L^2$ but true for $L^p$?

Comment: Looking at $p= \infty, k = 1$ might be a good idea, because [(locally)  uniform limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_convergence) stays holomorphic